# Divide the page in two (vertically) among two children, if one not available, other should cover complete page

Tags: css, html, layout

[image: Two scenarios]

I hope the pictures describes what I want. Currently both the child div have `height:50%` 
However, when one of them is absent, I want the other to cover the entire page.

I am looking for a `css` only solution as I presume I'm missing something very fundamental! :P

Answer (score 1):

Without using the flex model or JavaScript, good luck :)

If you're okay with only modern browsers, then use the flex layout. Make a container with `flex-direction: column` and give each div inside a flex value of `flex: 1 1 auto;`.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mcclosdl/sQXwe/) fiddle.

Comment: This is great! :) I'm tempted to use this but unfortunately, I HAVE to support IE 7+ and I suppose flex will go for a toss on IE 7,8,9 X-/ any suggestions?

Comment: AFAIK, you'll have to use a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Okay. And the javascript solution will be to increase the height of visible child to 100%, right?

Comment: Yeah if you're sure that there is only ever 1 or 2.